# Separate Database in Neo4j 3.1 Enterprise Edition

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying Neo4j 3.1 enterprise edition and I want to have several different graphs.

In community edition you just choose your db folder and it switches between databases but here I do not know how to have several different databases e.g. imagine I'm working on two different graph projects at the same time. How should I manage different databases and switch between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach of choosing the graph db directory with Enterprise Edition. Just edit `neo4j.conf` and set `dbms.active_database`:

```
dbms.active_database=GRAPH_DIR_YOU_WANT_TO_MOUNT
```

and then restart Neo4j.

Alternatively, you can run multiple Neo4j instances on the same machine, just edit `neo4j.conf` to have them listen on different ports.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Wiliam! It is a good solution but restarting the database everytime does not seem to be practical. How is it possible to do it without any need to restarting? Does mutiple instances solve this problem?